# Google Maps API v3 TypeScript Definition File bool instead of Boolean

Tags: javascript, typescript, nuget, visual-studio-2017

After installing the latest Typescript Definition file for Google Maps using NuGet in Visual Studio 2017.

```
Install-Package google.maps.d.ts -Version 1.0.10
```

I get 118 occurrences of the following compiler error.
Error   TS2304  (TS) Cannot find name 'bool'

My work around was to replace all occurrences of bool with Boolean.

Is there another way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there another way to fix this problem?

AFAIK, what have you done is the correct way to fix this problem.

**The type bool was renamed to `boolean` in TypeScript 0.9** - the definitely typed declaration should been updated for this change for `google.maps`. But the latest update of this package is January 17, 2013 (1/17/2013):

[image]

After installed this package, we noticed that the definitely typed declaration are still use `bool`, so we need update those definitely typed declaration from `bool` to `boolean` manually before the author updates the package, otherwise, you may need to use the previous version of typescripts 0.9 in Visual Studio 2017.